# How to make makefile host dependent?

Tags: linux, makefile

I need to compile my program with or without some libraries depending on which of the two hosts it is running. I don't know what to use at the right side of `HOST=` in my makefile to make this work as I want it to:

```
   ifeq(${HOST},${ADDITIONAL_LIBS_HOST})
   ADD_LIBS= ...
```

`${ADDITIONAL_LIBS_HOST}` is the name of host as gotten from 
`echo ${HOSTNAME}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- This is the sort of situation GNU autoconf was designed to address.  Run `./configure`, figure out what libraries are available, and generate an appropriate Makefile.
- You could get the current hostname by doing something like:

  ```
  HOST=$(shell hostname)
  ```

  You could then use this in your conditional.
- You could instead have your Makefile do something like:

  ```
  include Makefile.local
  ```

  And then have different Makefile.local files on each host.

Re: your comment, given a Makefile like this:

```
HOST=$(shell hostname)

all:
    @echo $(HOST)
```

Will generate the following output:

```
$ make all
fafnir.local
```

(Assuming your local host is "fafnir.local".  Which mine is.)

Comment: `HOST=$(shell HOSTNAME)` does not work, I've tried it already. But I don't know how could I miss the include directive. Thank You very much.

Comment: `HOST=$(shell hostname)` works fine.  Notice that you have decided for whatever reason to capitalize `HOSTNAME`, which is not actually the name of a command.

Comment: erm, I've tried to use environmental variable HOSTNAME, and so I used $(shell `HOSTNAME`), `$(shell ${HOSTNAME})`, `$(shell $${HOSTNAME})` and whatever came to my mind. I didn't know that there is actually a command `hostname`. And of course You are right, `HOST=$(shell hostname)` works fine.

Comment: If you're using an environmental variable than you wouldn't use the $(shell ...) directive, which is used to run a command.  For an environment variable you just use it like a normal make variable (e.g., $(HOME)).

Comment: It seems that `HOST=$(HOSTNAME)` doesn't work (tried on two *buntu PC's). HOME on the other hand does.

Answer (score 1):

The `hostname` console command is not present on all distributions, especially for distributions with systemd.

The `uname` command can be used as an alternative.

```
hostname := $(shell uname -n)

default:
  @echo $(hostname)
```